# How to add object to a lower level node in JS?

Tags: javascript, redux, immer.js

I try this:

```js
getProgramTicketsRes.data.layout.sectors[action.payload.sectorName][
    action.payload.rowNum
].rowComponents[action.payload.rowComponentNum].bookingStates[
    action.payload.eventTimeId
] = {}
```

but it raise an error, why? All the upper level nodes exist, I check with code, is not written here.

This is how I create variable with `Immer`. Code is used in a Redux resolver.

```js
let getProgramTicketsRes = { ...current(state.getProgramTicketsRes) }
```

Comment: What is `state.getProgramTicketsRes`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `current` here. In an `immer` reducer, you should modify the `state` object, not some temporary snapshot extracted with `current`. That will definitely fail! Use `current` only for `console.log`, not for anything else.

```js
state.getProgramTicketsRes.data.layout.sectors[action.payload.sectorName][
    action.payload.rowNum
].rowComponents[action.payload.rowComponentNum].bookingStates[
    action.payload.eventTimeId
] = {}
```